# Post-compromise security scan; anything else?

Tags: security, virus, spyware, trojan

My girlfriend checked her Gmail yesterday morning, and then found, later on in the day, that it would no longer accept her password.  She also found that this happened to her Hotmail and Yahoo! accounts.

She's only checked these accounts from her work and home PC, and I've spent the day checking the home PC for problems.  A full AVG scan revealed a couple of installers for her webcam software that had questionable security signatures, and a full Windows Defender scan brought back nothing.

Assuming that her home PC was compromised, somehow, is there anything else I should use to check it for some sort of lingering malicious app before I tell her it's okay to login to her accounts, again?

Furthermore, she's going through the GMail "account recovery" process as the account appears to have been disabled.  Does anyone know if this actually works?

Thanks so much.
IVR Avenger

Comment: Try Malwarebytes as well. Also good in a pinch

Comment: It's been a month since the question was asked, if one of the answers fits please accept it, otherwise please explain why the answer does not fit.

Answer (score 0):

I think the AVG scan will be enough to thoroughly clean the computer of viruses. Yes, the GMail account recovery works, but it's a lot easier if you've got a secondary email set. And obviously, change any other passwords that the computer may have had access to.

Answer (score 0):

If her usernames and passwords were taken either from social engineering or hacking another site when she uses the same password everywhere there is little you can do or will find other than to start changing all sites she uses with new passwords and maybe using a different one on each site. If things have come back clean and there are no rootkits on either computer someone has her usernames and passwords via other methods, either way it is time to change the password. If you want to do another scan with an offline OS user [TRK](http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?wpid=1&front_id=12) with [virusscan](http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?wpid=40&front_id=12).